# Why is my AJAX request failing when I do it with JQuery, but it works when I do it with a browser extension (RESTED)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, typescript

I'm trying to automate sending emails with the [Zoho API](https://www.zoho.eu/mail/help/api/post-send-an-email.html).

I got an Auth Token, and I tried to make a POST request to their API with the Firefox extension [RESTED](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/rested/), and it worked, the test email is sent successfully as many times as I want.

So then I tried to implement it in javascript with JQuery, but it doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.

The request is structured like this on RESTED:

```
URL: "The URL of the API",
Method: "POST",

Headers:

Authorization: "The auth token",
Content-Type: "application/json"

and then request body:

{
    "fromAddress": "my email",
    "toAddress": "target email",
    "subject": "the subject",
    "content": "The body"
}
```

And that works fine.

Then that's what I wrote in my Javascript (typescript)

```
const zohoURL = "The URL of the API";
const headers = {
  "Authorization": "The auth token",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
};

const messageObject = {
    "fromAddress": "my email",
    "toAddress": "target email",
    "subject": "the subject",
    "content": "The body"
};

$.ajax({
  "type": "POST",
  "headers": headers,
  "url": zohoURL,
  "data": messageObject
}).done(done => {
  console.log("DONE: ", done);
}).fail(err => {
  console.error("ERROR: ", err);
});
```

But it keeps failing, no matter what I try. I tried setting the headers to allow CORS, changing the dataType of the ajax request, using JSON.Stringify() on the object, but nothing worked.

In the console I noticed that when I use the Firefox extension to make the request, there is

```
origin moz-extension://some id
```

and when doing it from javascript, the origin is localhost. Could it be that the request is denied because it's starting from localhost?

Error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mail.zoho.com/api/accounts/... (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

I tried adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" to the header, but nothing changes.

Comment: Learn what CORS actually is.  You need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the _response_.

Comment: Code running from within a page served up is different from code running as part of a browser extension. The browser imposes strict rules on page code, including rules about making ajax requests to other domains. If you don't control the Zoho servers, then you cannot use JavaScript from within web content to access the API. You'd have to use your own proxy server.

Comment: Would the request work if sent from a server instead of from the client?

It was supposed to be on the server from the start, but I was first testing it client-side.

Comment: I tried running it from my server instead of from the client, and it still doesn't work.

I don't know what to do please, help.